# IVideoWindows shows outside form when use MDI

Tags: c#, winapi, directshow, mdi, video-conferencing

I'm using the ConferenceXP source code, when I try to set the video windows as child inside my form using MDI the IVideoWindows opens outside in a different ActiveMovie windows.
I need this to make a video conference in HD with C# embebbed into my solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Video renderer opens a popup window when it is connected, however it is not properly initialized. This, in turn, typically takes place when the whole filter graph is built incorrectly or inaccurately, esp. when application's request such as `RenderFile` adds a new renderer which the application is not even aware of.

To address this type of issues, you need to first of all find out what is the effective graph topology in your application.

Comment: thanks I'll check the topology, though I made a work around solution.